# Uniform convergence theorem fails when |E| =$\infty$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

Uniform Convergence Theorem: Let $f_k \in L(E)$ for $k=1,2,...$, and let ${f_k}$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $E$, $|E|<\infty$. Then $f\in L(E)$ and $\int_E f_k \rightarrow \int_E f $.

I need to show this fails if $|E|=\infty$. I have been trying to find a sequence of functions that converge uniformly over $\mathbb{R}$ but whatever I chose wasn't lebesgue integrable, I get the lebesgue integral is $\infty$.

Can someone give a hint? Thanks

Comment: Try to make $f$ non-integrable. The most obvious non-integrable function on an infinite measure space is a nonzero constant, but you can't do that, because then all but finitely many $f_k$ would all be bounded away from zero by some constant, so they wouldn't be integrable. The next choice is something with a non-integrable decaying tail, like $x^p 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$ for $p \geq -1$. Can you make up a sequence of integrable functions which converge uniformly to $x^{-1} 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$?

Comment: How about $f_n(x)=x^{-1}$ for  $x\in [1,n],$ and $f_n(x)= -2^{-n}$ for $x\in  (n,B_n],$  and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x> B_n,$ where $B_n=  n+ 2^n\int_1^n (1/x)dx .$

Comment: A simpler example is just $x^{-1} 1_{[1,n]}(x)$; here the supremum of the error is $1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $f_n= \frac1n \chi_{(0,n)}$. Then, $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, where $f \equiv 0$.

We have that for all $n$, $\int_{\Bbb R} f_n d \lambda = \frac1n \lambda((0,n)) = 1$, so $(f_n) \subset L^1(\Bbb R)$.

But $\int_{\Bbb R} f d \lambda = 0$ and $\lim \int_{\Bbb R} f_n d \lambda = 1$.

Comment: A valid approach to the problem at hand, which reveals a different interesting phenomenon from my example. +1.